# Utility for viewing which files/dlls are loaded by an executable image

Tags: windows, visual-studio, dll, windows-7, utilities

I know there is a utility for this because I used to use it...just can't remember the name.  I'm looking for a Windows (Windows-7) utility that will allow me to select an executable image running and have it tell me what files/dlls that program has loaded and from what directory.  I am writing software in Visual Studio and would like to verify at runtime which dlls my program is loading.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

use [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645) or [Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653).

Comment: That's it "Process Explorer"...excellent little utility. Thanks!

Comment: You forgot to say how to do it with process explorer. It shows lot of stuff, but I don't see list of DLL files anywhere.

Comment: To see DLLs loaded by a process with PE, select `View->Lower Pane View->DLLs`.

Answer (score 24):

Visual Studio does it well.  Use Tools > Attach to Process, Debug > Break All.  Then Debug > Windows > Modules.  For VS2015+ start that with Debug > Attach to Process.

Answer (score 4):

The command line route is [ListDLLs](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896656.aspx) from Sysinternals.

It can list DLLs loaded by a process, or list processes that loaded a given DLL.

Comment: Keep out: in some cases, the list, provided by the mentioned tool, is incomplete.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of installing any third-party tools, we could use Microsoft's [`tasklist`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/tasklist). E.g., to display the loaded DLLs for a program using its name, do this:

```
C:\>tasklist /m /fi "imagename eq PacketAnalyzerPlus.exe"

Image Name                     PID Modules
========================= ======== ============================================
PacketAnalyzerPlus.exe        3904 ntdll.dll, wow64.dll, wow64win.dll,
                                   wow64cpu.dll
```

where the specified options are as below:

> /m <module> - Lists all tasks with DLL modules loaded that match the given pattern name. If the module name is not specified, this option displays all modules loaded by each task.
>
> /fi <filter> - Specifies the types of processes to include in or exclude from the query. You can use more than one filter or use the wildcard character () to specify all tasks or image names.

If it is a Windows service, use filter `services`. E.g. to find all DLLs for service `Winmgmt`, use this:

```
C:\>tasklist /m /fi "services eq Winmgmt"

Image Name                     PID Modules
========================= ======== ============================================
svchost.exe                    872 ntdll.dll, kernel32.dll, KERNELBASE.dll,
                                   msvcrt.dll, sechost.dll, RPCRT4.dll,
                                   ole32.dll, GDI32.dll, USER32.dll, LPK.dll,
                                   USP10.dll, IMM32.DLL, MSCTF.dll,...
```